# Android Java Class

Tags: java, android, class

I'm very new to Android, sorry for the probably simple quenstion that i ask to you.
I've searched in various Question but i didn't find anything...

This is a little application, to create a Class Persona with parameters as Name, Surname, Age, etc.

I insert the text in an editText separated by a space

*Es. John Smith 35*

then click on button and add field to Persona.java instance.

```
persona[0].nome = John
persona[0].cognome = Smith
persona[0].eta = 35
```

and so on for the next person that i want to insert

```
persona[1].nome = ......
...

persona[2].nome =....
```

What i want is to create various instance of Persona class one for every person i want to save various parameter.

But unfortunately when i click button it gave me error.

Listing activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:inputType="text"/>      

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Nome" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"

    android:text="Button" />
```

Listing Persona.java

```
package com.gio.imparareandroid;

public class Persona{
String nome;
String cognome;
String indirizzo;
String numeroCellulare;
int eta;
int annoNascita;
int meseNascita;
int giornoNascita;  
}
```

Listing MainActivity.java

```
package com.gio.imparareandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.gio.imparareandroid.Persona;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String contenutoText;
EditText input; 
Button btOk; 
TextView text; 
String[] separated = new String[10];
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int numeroParole;
Persona[] persona = new Persona[10];
int contatorePersone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    contatorePersone = 0;
    btOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // inizializza variabili
            numeroParole = 0;
            builder.setLength(0);
            contenutoText = input.getText().toString();
            estrapola(contenutoText);
            pulisci();
            stampaVariabili();
            contatorePersone ++;
        }
    });
}

void pulisci(){
    input.setText("");
}


public void estrapola(String testoGrezzo){

    int contatoreParole;
    contatoreParole = 1;
    separated = testoGrezzo.split("\\ ");

    persona[contatorePersone].nome = separated[0];
    persona[contatorePersone].cognome = separated[1];
    try {
        persona[contatorePersone].eta = Integer.parseInt(separated[2]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          //Will Throw exception!
          //do something! anything to handle the exception.
    } 
    for (String item : separated)
    {           
        builder.append("Parola numero " + contatoreParole + " : " + item);
        builder.append("\n");           
        contatoreParole ++;
    }
    text.setText(builder.toString());
    numeroParole = contatoreParole-1;
}

private void stampaVariabili() {

    for (int p = 0; p == contatorePersone ; p++){
        String cassetto = text.getText().toString();
        text.setText(cassetto + persona[p].nome + persona[p].cognome + persona[p].eta);
    }
    String cassetto = text.getText().toString();
    text.setText(cassetto + "\n" + "\n" + "Totale Persone Memorizzate: "+ contatorePersone + 1);
}
```

}

If you have any suggestion, help me please!

Comment: Define "don't work". It seems like you need a basic introduction to Java before using android. At the moment where this code is executed, rawText is probably empty and counter is probably 0. But we can' know since you didn't post the relevant code. Also, stop catching and ignoring exceptions. Don't catch them, and you'll have a complete stack trae, with a meaninful error message, which helps you identifying the cause and location of the problem. Catching the exception prevents you from getting this useful information. You're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: This doesn't even compile

Comment: What is not working? Crash maybe? How does `rawText` look like?

Comment: Sorry, i edited with complete code "as is" without ttranslating in english...

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to normal Java classes, an `Activity` is utilized by the Android framework. The framework calls the activity's `onCreate(Bundle)` method when it is first created, which is where you should place your initialization code.

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

[For more information, you should read this article: "Starting an Activity"](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.
The form

```
persona[contatorePersone].nome = separated[0];
persona[contatorePersone].cognome = separated[1];
```

was wrong.

The right code was:

```
Persona[contatorePersone] = new Persona (separated[0],separated[1]);

Persona[contatorePersone].getNome()
Persona[contatorePersone].getCognome()
```

Sorry for my English, if it was bad.